Passing user data to a crawler
I have this function
async function extractFromSearchPage(url, log) {
    searchOptions = {'somevalue'}
    likelyPaginationButtonResponse = {'somevalue'}
    await searchPageCrawler.run([{
        url: url,
        userData: {
            searchOptions: searchOptions,
            paginationButton: likelyPaginationButtonResponse
        }}])

}
    

And I want to pass userData to this crawler
// Function to interact with the page using Playwright
const searchPageCrawler = new PlaywrightCrawler({
    launchContext: {
        launchOptions: {
            launcher: 'firefox',
            headless: false, // Run in head-full mode to mimic a real user
            firefoxUserPrefs: {
                'general.useragent.override': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0', // Example user agent
            },
            args: [
                '--disable-web-security', // Disables web security to prevent CORS issues
                '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process', // Disables site isolation
                '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=true', // Ensures images are loaded
            ]
        },
        // stealth: true, // Use stealth plugin to prevent detection
    },
    async requestHandler({ page, request, session, log }) {
        log.info(`Starting the crawler.`);
        log.info(`Processing search page at URL: ${request.url}`);
        log.info(`Processing search page at URL: ${request.url} with details: ${JSON.stringify(session)}`);
        log.info(`Processing search page at URL: ${request.url} with details: ${JSON.stringify(session.userData)}`);
    
        await page.goto(request.url);
        await page.waitForSelector('body'); // Ensure the page has loaded
    
});

But right now session.userData shows up as empty.
INFO  PlaywrightCrawler: Interacting with search page using details: {}
INFO  PlaywrightCrawler: session.userData: {}
INFO  PlaywrightCrawler: searchDetails: undefined
Even though the data is instantiated in extractFromSearchPage() and has a value there

I was using session.userData when I should have been using request.userData
